# Using TAP::Formatter::JUnit with Mojolicious tests?

Tags: perl, testing, mojolicious

I have a number of tests for my Mojolicious application and that all works fine, and now I'm trying to get Mojolicious to output to JUnit XML. I've found `TAP::Formatter::JUnit` which looks like it's exactly what I want, but I'm not grasping how to get the Mojolicious tests (run by just `script/site.pl test` from the root level of my application) to use that.

Am I missing something blindly obvious, or am I not able to use Mojolicious' built-in testing functionality if I want it outputted to JUnit XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into [Mojolicious::Command::test](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojolicious%3A%3ACommand%3A%3Atest) and it is using `Test::Harness` to run the test suite. The module is wrapper over `TAP::Harness`, whose `formatter` parameter we need to set. I haven't found any way how to push the parameter through (there are environment variables like `HARNESS_OPTIONS`, but they did not allow for the parameter).

What you can do is to implement [new command for your application](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Adding_commands_to_Mojolicious). I created new Mojolicious application, added new command namespace per the guide above in application startup:

```
push @{$self->commands->namespaces}, 'JUnitTest::Command';
```

Then I just copied `Mojolicious::Command::test` into `JUnit::Command::testjunit` and replaced last lines of `run` method:

```
$ENV{HARNESS_OPTIONS} //= 'c';
require Test::Harness;
Test::Harness::runtests(sort @args);
```

with

```
require TAP::Harness;
my $harness = TAP::Harness->new({
  formatter_class => 'TAP::Formatter::JUnit',
  lib   => \@INC,
  merge => 1,
});
$harness->runtests(sort @args);
```

Running it as

```
perl script/junit_test testjunit
```

resulted in this output:

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite failures="0" errors="0" tests="3" name="t_basic_t">
    <testcase name="1 - get /"></testcase>
    <testcase name="2 - 200 OK"></testcase>
    <testcase name="3 - content is similar"></testcase>
    <system-out><![CDATA[1..3
ok 1 - get /
ok 2 - 200 OK
ok 3 - content is similar
]]></system-out>
    <system-err></system-err>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Raised an issue [here](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/issues/454) to have the ability to specify formatters.

Comment: @VirtualWolf - glad this helped. Raising the issue might lead to improving of test command, so we can use alternative formatters without much effort.